# Partial transparent table view cells swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I can easily make a cell fully transparent (clear color) so the background image shines through tableview and tableview cells.

However, what I really want is a cell that is 50% transparent - i.e. so background image shines through. . ... Is what I am trying to accomplish not possible? I already define alpha/opacity in the color I use when setting background color, but it seems like it is ignored (the rest of color is correct)

Here's my code (originally ported from another language/tool)

```
class ViewControllerCatalog: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var outletCatalog: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: FBackgroundImage.Content!);
    outletCatalog.delegate = self;
    outletCatalog.dataSource = self;
    outletCatalog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
  }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated);
    // ... load data
    outletCatalog.reloadData();
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = nil;
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic", forIndexPath: indexPath); 
    let idx: Int = indexPath.row;
    // ... set other stuff        
    cell!.backgroundColor = Int64_To_UIColor(FCatalogArr.data_array![idx].background_color_int);    
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = Int64_To_UIColor(FCatalogArr.data_array![idx].background_color_int);    
    cell!.opaque = false;
}     

// included here in full details - basicly I get colors as 4byte ints (although in int64) with alpha and rgb
func Int64_To_UIColor(AColor: Int64) -> UIColor {
  //var StrDebug: String = "";
  //StrDebug = String(format: "%2X", AColor);
  var AI64: Int64 = AColor >> 24;
  var RI64: Int64 = AColor >> 16;
  var GI64: Int64 = AColor >> 08;
  var BI64: Int64 = AColor >> 00;
  AI64 = AI64 & 0xff;
  //StrDebug = String(format: "%2X", AI64);
  RI64 = RI64 & 0xff;
  //StrDebug = String(format: "%2X", RI64);
  GI64 = GI64 & 0xff;
  //StrDebug = String(format: "%2X", GI64);
  BI64 = BI64 & 0xff;
  //StrDebug = String(format: "%2X", BI64);
  let AF: CGFloat = CGFloat(AI64) / 255;
  let RF: CGFloat = CGFloat(RI64) / 255;
  let GF: CGFloat = CGFloat(GI64) / 255;
  let BF: CGFloat = CGFloat(BI64) / 255;
  let res: UIColor = UIColor(red: RF, green: GF, blue: BF, alpha: AF);
  return res;
}

}
```

Where

- *outletCatalog* is the tableview
- color / byte values are correct when converting to color

And yes, I am using storyboard, but I try set values in code since it is easier to inspect and debug and post to SO. I would prefer a solution that would at least *also* work when using code since I load content and styling from configuration and data files at runtime.

Comment: are you setting the alpha on the tableview background color, or just the cells? Are you using storyboards? Can you please provide some code where you are doing this? We need more information.

Comment: Have your set the cell's and its content view's `opaque=false`?

Comment: @Siriss transparency works if i use clear color on the cells so yes, the tableview itself is fully transparen (the background image set in the the view behind the tableview shines through)

Comment: @Tapani - I have posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, what I really want is a background color that is 50% transparent - i.e. so background image shines through. ... Is what I am trying to accomplish not possible

It is possible. In this screen shot we have a table with five cells:

[image]

The cells are a transparent red, which is what I've asked for. And you can see that this is working correctly, because below the five cells you see the background with no cells in front of it, and it is not tinted red. Thus, where the cells are, the image shines through the 50% transparency of the red cells, exactly as you describe.

Comment: That's the effect i am after

Comment: Well I believe that answers the question you asked. It is possible.

Comment: I am not so sure yet. I believe I already tried most before posting here, but who know, I might be wrong

Comment: Well wait a second. Your question was "is it possible". I didn't cheat: I created an iOS project, added a couple of lines of code, and made a screen shot. If I achieved the effect you are after, that proves it is possible. So I answered your question.

Comment: It's not a "play". This is not about me. Your question has been definitively answered. I don't see why you don't get that.

Comment: You won't acknowledge you are playing? :) Even when you know I was looking for a solution. (Indirect) point taken for my fault in only describing what I had tried instead of posting code - but that you try pretend you are not playing/trolling is kinda... well, just censored myself. I guess you won since I took your bait :) Anyhow, I do truly appreciate your answer since it would seem that it under some circumstances is possible - I will try work my way through finding out what they are - so I think an upvote is the correct thing to do here.

Comment: "Even when you know I was looking for a solution" (1) You never asked how to do it. You asked if it could be done. That is what I answered. (2) Your code is incomprehensible to me. I would never use `willDisplayCell:` for this (or much of anything), and you're using a bunch of calls that make no sense to me. So I don't know how to fix _your_ code. _My_ code is simple. I set the `backgroundColor` of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The end. If you want to keep shooting yourself in the foot by doing a bunch of stuff that doesn't work, fine. But stuff that does work, works.

Comment: 1)  I will assume you could deduce I was looking for a solution, if you maintain something else that's okay with me 2) I based my code on other SO entries, but now fixed where background is set - no difference yet, but still thanks! 3) I updated code. Yes, I could have chosen to *not* write the code that extracts alpha rgb from 4byte in an int, but I included it written in a *very* simple way so people could see how the color was constructed (otherwise it would be obvious to suspect the color generation as faulty) 4) I suspect you set either background or other properties in a way I have not

Comment: You can suspect what you like. Setting every cell's background color is really really all I did. Of course I also set the text label just to show that these are cells, but that is irrelevant. I did no configuration in IB at all; this is a plain vanilla out of the box table view controller and its table.

Comment: In your viewDidLoad() do you also set self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: ...); where the tableview is placed on top of that with and with backgroundColor set to UIColor.clearColor(); ? It works fine when cell background is set to clearColor(), but I have sofar not been able to get transparent cells working. But I have something to try now from what you write.

Comment: Exactly my point! I suggest you forget your project and your code for a while and just do what I did. Make a new simple project to prove to yourself that this is easy with just a couple of lines of code. Then you can disentangle whatever mess you've evidently made of this in your real project.

Comment: For others reading his SO with the same problem: Per apple documentation, *their* example uses willDisplayCell https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html when chaning background color in a cell

Comment: @Tom Yes, this was necessary back in (can't quite remember) iOS 4 or 5 or thereabouts. But no longer. Apple is not good at cleaning up the docs when things change.

Comment: I have now successfully in xcode/IB made a cell appear translucient. (And I found out that if your color opaciy is set down, the opaque and alpha properies are not used.) I am still not successfull in getting it working in code, but I will try... maybe fetch the colors and analyze the byte values. I *need* to be able to set all colors in code, so I can not rely on premade cells.